Cardano API key HttpClient Authorization
ers
I've obtained a free API key (FreeApiKey) in order to find all my transactions easily. I've written this query in C# using .NET but I'm stuck on how to specify the authorization using this key.  I've got as far as:
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
new AuthenticationHeaderValue("apiKey", FreeApiKey);
but when I issue the HttpResponseMessage request I get "Unauthorized access" etc. etc.
What am I doing wrong? All suggestions gratefully received.
Thanks
